# amcharts balloon visiblity when mouse is over it?

Tags: javascript, plugins, mouse, visible, balloon

How to make amcharts balloon to be visible when mouse is over it? Here is the doc about the balloon http://docs.amcharts.com/2/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon

Answer (score 0):

For instance if you use the column type. The Balloon appears by defaults.

```
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.valueField = "visits"; //this is from my Json data
graph.type = "column"; //here is the type of graph
```

Now if you wish you can access and modify the balloon object

```
// here I modify the default outputted text     
graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>";
```